# How can I specify a directory for a temporary file in PHP?

Tags: php, function, file, class, temporary-files

I have written a PHP templating engine for parsing text into valid php code before executing. Currently I keep of this file in memory then `eval()` after parsing into valid php code. After researching more on the evils of using `eval()` with user input I have found it wiser to write the parsed content to a file and then `include` the file. I am using `tmpfile()` function for this. So far it doen not work, besides, I dunno where this temporary file is created and I would not like my template parser loitering files anyhow on a user's filesystem. I would like to have this temp file created in the same directory as resides the template parser class.
Now, problem is, `tmpfile()` does not take any parameter as shown here http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php . 
Below is my template parser class

```
<?php
class TemplateParser {

  //this method renders template file
  public function render($file_path)
  {
    #...code to compile contents

    //create temporary file and store handle
    $file_handler = tmpfile();

    //write contents to tmpfile()       
    fwrite($file_handler,$compiled_template_file_contents);

    //close opened file
    fclose($file_handler);

    //include the file into the current script
    include $file_handler; //this doesn't work, now what works?? coz this is not a valid filepath but a resource

  }

}
```

I need to know the file path because I want to be sure that I don't leave garbage even in case of a fatal error, or killed process by calling `unlink($tmp_file_path)` Any ideas on how to define a dir for `tmpfile()` during this script execution only? I will appreciate.

Comment: try using [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Comment: A short look into the documentation shows: http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is executing code from file safer than executing code from a string?

Comment: Yeah. I know `tempnam()` exists which also can end up using the system's `tmp` directory if the directory specified for it does not exist or is not writable. Well I wanted to ensure `tmpfile()` cannot help completely before I trade for another option so that it's over and done with. This function here `sys_get_temp_dir()` gives me the path to the tmp dir but not the file name created. Is there a way to know the full path including the file name and is there a function for altering the tmp file path?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Evils of `eval` Caution

The `eval()` language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand in this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php Besides it is not possible to catch a parse error in `eval()` using `set_error_handler()`. Plus others is reason enough to leave this function alone...

Answer (score 1):

The `tmpfile()` function creates file in the system's `TMP` dir. Where it is you can get with `sys_get_temp_dir()`.

Some more control gives you `tempnam()`. But don't forget to cleanup after yourself.

If you use `tmpfile()` you don't have to delete the file manually. According to documentation:

> The file is automatically removed when closed (for example, by calling `fclose()`, or when there are no remaining references to the file handle returned by `tmpfile()`), or when the script ends.

To `include` the content of the file you can try following:

```
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir());

// create content with fopen(), fwrite(), fclose()

include $filename;

unlink($filename);
```

I would suggest to use instead some kind of modern templating libraries like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

Comment: This function here `sys_get_temp_dir()` gives me the path to the `tmp dir` but not the `file name` created. Is there a way to know the `full path` including the file name and is there a function for altering the tmp file path?

Comment: @geoff6837 The file will be automatically deleted, as soon as you close it.

Comment: You are right. So how do a load the contents  of this file to my current script using `include $path_to_tmp_file;` ?